# iOS 5 Twitter framework. Getting OAuth access token for user

Tags: objective-c, ios5, twitter, twitter-oauth, twrequest

Has anyone been able to get the OAuth access token for a user after being granted access to that users account?

twitter mentions using a process called "Reverse Auth" in there iOS docs, but I can't seem to find any mention of it anywhere else.

I'm feeling a little lost here so if any one can provide some inside it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More information on using Reverse Auth has been released by Twitter [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth).

Comment: I'm having trouble generating the signed request for step 1. Do we actually have to create the request headers ourself or can we use TWRequest somehow? I keep getting this error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

Comment: Yes, this is a dummy question but is there a function from ios framework to send this request (such as TwRequest) ?

Comment: From my understanding, you have to generate the request yourself. This is the only way you could get a token and secret to get at the access_token endpoint.

Comment: Link is now dead, does anyone have a fresh source?